# GWT DOM not working

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want to append **div** inside <**TH**> in **GWT**

```js
Element tr = DOM.createTR();

DOM.appendChild(thead, tr);
for (int index = 0; index < headers.size(); index++) {
Element th = DOM.createTH();

Element div = DOM.createDiv();

DOM.appendChild(th, div);   // this is not working !
DOM.appendChild(tr, th);

}
```

Is any thing wrong in my code?

Comment: how you created thead ? and what is not working? giving compile time error? run time error?

Comment: using thead = DOM.createElement("thead"); 
i created thead...

Comment: I want <thead><tr><th><div></div></th></tr></thead>

Comment: and after compile time or run time, i don't see any error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume it will give you compile time error because the method `DOM.appendChild(th, div);'  second parameter should be part of package structure:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Element
```

instead of

```
com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element
```